# Chrome browser full screen

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

We have a web based application installed locally using PHP server (xammp)- We are currently using Chrome browser to run the app on windows based machines. We were looking at ways of launching the program/app in full screen mode (no URL bar)- completely full screen. We found a way around using the apps page in chrome (create shortcut, open in full screen- create short cut and drop in startup folder).

The issue is now with the latest release of chrome, this function (open in full screen)- has now been removed and the option doesnt exist thus causing our software to open in a small window.

Does anybody have any ideas how to stablize this and enable our web based program to launch full screen every time without serious dependencies?

Comment: stuck up with same issue. did you got any solution